# paperclip adding picture to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I want to add a picture to a user by using paperclip in my rails application

my form looks like this:

```
    <%= form_tag :controler => "users", :action => :uploadimage, :class => "form-horizontal", html: { multipart: true }, :method => :post do |f| %>

    <input type="hidden" id="user" name="userid" value="<%= @user.id %>" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="file" name="upload[image]" required="true" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <%#= f.submit t("main.save"), :icon => :save, :onclick => "validate(); return false;" %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

the upload action looks like this:

```
  def uploadimage
if request.post?
  @user = User.find(params[:userid])
  if @user.update_attribute(:image, params[:image])
    flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
    redirect_to :action => :settings
  end
end
end
```

Its done properly, but in database it's nothing added and in filestorage also not.

user model has this:

```
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200" },
                :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/:id/:filename",
                :url => "/uploads/:id/:filename"

 validates_attachment :image, :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" }
```

Database migration is done properly all needed fields were setup in users table.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `params[:image]` should be `params[:upload][:image]` because the `name` of the **input field** in the form is `upload[image]`

```
def uploadimage
  if request.post?
    @user = User.find(params[:userid])
    if @user.update_attribute(:image, params[:upload][:image])
      flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
      redirect_to :action => :settings
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got a error, I've added the message above

Comment: problem solved - form tag is set like this:

    <%= form_for(:user, :url => '/users/uploadimage', :html => {:multipart => true, :class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| -%>